# Angular ui-select with refresh "delete the associated model"

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

I'm working with Angular 1.5 and ui-select with a refresh function.

I've created a small crud service in order to manage an entity.
Altough the ui-select with the refresh function this works well during the creation, for the "edit" it does not work.

The associated ng-model, filled with the preselected elements in the controller, is deleted once that page and the ui-select directive has been loaded

Someone have had this problem?
I posted the example of the html and the refresh function and the model.

Thanks in advance for the help

HTML:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="model" theme="bootstrap" ng-disalbed="disabled">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select linked entity...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.id}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices  repeat="entity.id as entity in entities | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}" >
        <div ng-bind-html="entity.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small ng-bind-html="entity.id">
            {{entity.id}}
        </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

ANGULAR:

```
$scope.getEntities = function(search,index){                                        
    return EntityService.getByIds({ids:$scope.entityIds.join(',')}).$promise.then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.entities = response;
        },
        function (response) {                                    
        })
        .finally(function() {
        }); 
    }
```

NG-MODEL and ENTITY :

```
$scope.model= [{id:"2",name:"test2"},{id:"4",name:"test4"}]
$scope.entities= [{id:"2",name:"test2"},{id:"4",name:"test4"},{id:"5",name:"test5"},{id:"6",name:"test6"}]
```

Comment: create a verifiable example on plunker maybe?

Comment: What do you mean with `refresh` function? As the ui-select supports a refresh function but I don't see it here. Next based on what I see could you try and change `as entity` into `as (key, entity)`  as from the [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-object-as-source.html)